# Why is the result of evaluating this function not being displayed in minibuffer?

Tags: echo-area, message

I wrote an interactive function to get the contents of a line from the current position of point to the last non-blank character on a line.

However, when after evaluating the function with `C-x C-e`,  going to a buffer with random-text and then typing `M-x get-substring-till-end-of-line` I would have expected the answer to be printed in the minibuffer.

But nothing prints in the mini-buffer.

Here is the code.

```
(defun get-substring-till-end-of-line ()
  "Get as a subtring all the characters from the 
   current-position of point upto the last 
   non-white space character of the current line."
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
      (let ((start (point)) end)
    (forward-line 1)
    (re-search-backward "[^[:space:]]")
    (setq end (point))
    (buffer-substring-no-properties start end))))
```

Comment: You need to send the result to the mini buffer through a call to message.

Comment: Was there a particular reason you expected that?  The expectation does not hold for any other interactive function you might have looked at, so I'm curious as to how/where you acquired it.

Comment: @phils Well the particular reason I probably unconsciously expected it,  was because I thought  since the result of evaluating the body of a function is usually the last form, I thought after evaluating the function the result would be displayed in the minibuffer automatically.  Kind of like how expressions once typed inside a python repl are evaluated and results are displayed automatically (without any appeal to print function).  I am still new to elisp and learning the ropes as I go along. :-D

Comment: Note that you wouldn't want commands to exhibit that behaviour -- every key binding calls a command, including inserting text (where keys are bound to `self-insert-command`, and which might frequently be happening at a minibuffer prompt), so things would be absurdly noisy if every command generated a message for its return value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `M-: (get-substring-till-end-of-line)` (or `M-x eval-expression ...`), it will print the value of the function call.

You can also use `message` for debugging, in your case, print the return value. Remove it when you don't need it.

---

BTW, `re-search-forward` has optional argument `BOUND` and `NOERROR`, they are helpful

```
(defun your-move-to-end-of-line ()
  "Move point to the last non-blank character of current line."
  (interactive)
  (and (re-search-forward (rx (1+ (in ?\s ?\t)) eol) (line-end-position) 'move)
       (goto-char (match-beginning 0))))

(defun your-get-substring-till-end-of-line ()
  (let ((start (point))
        (end (save-excursion
               (if (re-search-forward (rx (1+ (in ?\s ?\t)) eol) (line-end-position) t)
                   (match-beginning 0)
                 (line-end-position)))))
    (buffer-substring-no-properties start end)))
```

You can also use `string-trim-right` from `subr-x.el`, the code is very simple.

```
(string-trim-right (buffer-substring-no-properties (point) (line-end-position)))
```